# How to get Google OAuth2 access token in C++?

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use the FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) REST API for sending notifications from my C++ code. Currently, I use the legacy HTTP but want to migrate to HTTP v1 API. This requires getting an OAuth 2.0  access token based on a private key file in JSON format: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server?authuser=0.

I see there are different libraries (Java, node.js, Python) that enable one to generate an access token, but I think I will need to do that using REST since there is no library for C++.

Is there a way to get an access token by calling a REST API?

Thanks in advance!